# Shortest paths problem : generic algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Question : [image]

Answer : [image]

I don't understand the algorithm. Indeed, in the table, I don't understand which vertexes to choose for the "Candidates L" column for each iteration.

I put picture of the statement of the problem and the solution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The "generic algorithm" is a queue-based variant of the Bellman-Ford algorithm.  The use of a queue is motivated by the observation that relaxing an edge only produces a change in the distance of the sink node if the distance of the source node has changed.  To start off the computation, the distance of $v_1$, $d(v_1)$, is "changed" to $0$ and $v_1$ is added to the queue.

At each iteration the vertex of least index is removed from the queue.  Let this vertex be $u$.  All edges out of $u$ are examined.  Let one such edge be $(u,v)$ with weight $W(u,v)$.  If the current $d(v)$ is greater than $d(u) + W(u,v)$, $d(v)$ is updated and $v$ is enqueued.  The process continues until either the queue is empty (as in this case) or a negative cycle is detected.

A detailed explanation of the algorithm is found in Sedgewick and Wayne's *Algorithms*.